# MongoDB ISODate parse with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, date

I am using MongoDB 3 and I'm trying to get all purchases by day. The problem is that I have the following value in mongo:

```
"createDate" : ISODate("2016-04-11T17:57:12.960Z")
```

And I want to get all the purchases using the following date format dd/MM/yyyy. This is my method:

```
public List<Purchase> getPurchasesByDate(BigInteger company, Date date, PurchaseStatus status) {
     Query query = new Query();
     query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("createDate").lte(date).and("status").is(status.toString()).and("company").is(company.toString()));
     return mongoTemplate.find(query, Purchase.class);
}
```

This is what I seeing into mongo console:

```
{ "createDate" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2016-04-11T19:14:56.322Z"} } , "status" : "PAYED" , "company" : "1"}
```

Obviously is not returning any values. I'm calling my method like this `getPurchasesByDate(1, new Date(), PurchaseStatus.PAYED)`.

Does anybody knows how can I can get all documents by date using this format dd/MM/yyyy?

thanks